# dsymutil missing compiling GNU bash on iOS

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, clang, darwin, dsymutil

I'm trying to compile GNU bash 4.3.30 *on* (and for) my iPad 2, iOS 8.4 using Clang, ld64, cctools, GNU make and the iOS 8.1 SDK. When processing bashversion, Clang is "unable to execute dsymutil", and reports that it "doesn't exist", exiting with error 1.

```
$ make
(...)
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch armv7 -iphoneos_version_min 5.0.0 -syslibroot /var/mobile/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -o bashversion -lcrt1.3.1.o -L./lib/termcap /var/tmp/bashversion-814fa1.o buildversion.o -lSystem
 "dsymutil" -o bashversion.dSYM bashversion
clang: error: unable to execute command: Executable "dsymutil" doesn't exist!
clang: error: dsymutil command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bashversion] Error 1

$ echo $CC
clang --sysroot /var/mobile/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -v
$ clang --version
clang version 3.5.0 (trunk)
Target: armv7-apple-darwin-14.0.0
Thread model: posix
$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-
configured to support archs: i386 x86_64 armv4t armv5 armv6 armv7 armv7f armv7k armv8 arm64 arm64v8
$ which dsymutil
$ dsymutil
-sh: dsymutil: command not found
$ find / -name dsymutil
$
```

Apparently, my iPad has no dsymutil. So, where can I find one? Does it come with Xcode? Or is there any way to compile GNU bash 4.3.30 without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dsymutil is a closed source tool, and is not available for iOS.

But that's not much of a problem, just create a symlink to /bin/true,

i.e.

```
ln -s /bin/true /usr/bin/dsymutil
```